# Objective C uint8_t PHP equivalent

Tags: php, objective-c, types, binaryfiles

I am converting small `Objective C` code in `PHP` script to convert integer array to Binary File.

**Objective C code**

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t fj1;
    uint8_t fj2;
    uint8_t sr1;
    uint8_t sr2;
    uint8_t zh1;
    uint8_t zh2;
    uint8_t as1;
    uint8_t as2;
    uint8_t mg1;
    uint8_t mg2;
    uint8_t is1;
    uint8_t is2;
    
} struct_pt;

struct_pt g_p_t[366]= {
    1, 29, 2, 49, 8, 15, 11, 16, 13, 37, 14, 52,
    1, 29, 2, 49, 8, 16, 11, 17, 13, 37, 14, 53,
    1, 29, 2, 50, 8, 16, 11, 18, 13, 38, 14, 53,
…………..
    }

const char *filePath = "/Users/usr/path/to/folder/filename.bin”;

FILE *file = fopen(filePath, "wb");

if (file != NULL) {
        fwrite(g_p_t, sizeof(uint8_t), sizeof(g_p_t), file);
}
```

And here is my **PHP Code**

```
// array of 366 rows
$arr = [1, 29, 2, 49, 8, 15, 11, 16, 13, 37, 14, 52,
1, 29, 2, 49, 8, 16, 11, 17, 13, 37, 14, 53,
1, 29, 2, 50, 8, 16, 11, 18, 13, 38, 14, 53,
……..
];

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\”file.bin\"");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");


    for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 
        echo trim(pack("I", $arr[$i]));
    }


fclose($out);

?>
```

The Binary File generated by PHP is a bit different from the file generated by Obj-C. I suppose I need to do character encoding in PHP.

Can you please guide me what is the equivalent encoding of `uint8_t` in PHP?

Comment: your example code is C, not Objective-C. And your struct is pretty much the same as `struct { uint16_t fj; uint16_t sr; uint16_t zh; uint16_t as; uint16_t mg; uint16_t is; }  yourstructnametype; ` which means your `array[366]` should be `= {{...},{...},{...}};` because you set each *fj1* and then skip 11 char.

Comment: `struct_pt g_p_t[366]` is not the same as `uint8_t g_p_t[366]`.

Comment: @OlSen, yes I am following `{{...},{...},...{...}};` structure of type struct_pt. Sorry, bad practices. But does it really matter regarding my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

PHP `pack()` packs the data into Binary string by taking format parameter.

As I am using `"I" -> unsigned integer` in `pack()` give result of 32bit encoding. Then `trim()` removes extra spaces and resulting data become encoding of below 8bit.

I've tried to generate a single-byte string from a number by using `chr()` in PHP

```
echo chr($arr[$i]);
```

And it worked for me :).